# Rails mailer: generating an email without a user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-rails

I am creating a basic app using react-rails. There are no models involved, but I do have a need to generate emails through a simple form that looks like this:

[image]

Since I am using React, I need to generate an AJAX Post request and point it towards my rails mailer. In all the rails mailer examples I've seen, the mail is sent when a new user is created (in the users post path). I don't have a need for this. Is it possible to treat my mailer like a controller and post directly to the mailer? How would the routes look? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own mailers.

Take a look at the docs for ActionMailer:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

You'll *probably* want to call your Mailer from a Controller.  If this is an appointment form you should have an `AppointmentsController` with some action that calls the Mailer, renders a response, and perhaps sets a notice to give the user some feedback.

Comment: Called it from a controller and everything is working well. Thanks!